# Boot a live OS from external usb drive on a Silicon M1

Tags: hard-drive, usb, password, dual-boot, bootable-disk

I need to take a dd image of a MacBook (Model A2179) EMC 3302 hard disk.

I have no way to recover the password to access the system, so I was going to live boot something like puppy or ubuntu to dd the disk to another device for forensic purpose and then wipe it, but looks like recovery mode isn't seeing any of the bootable USBs.

I am using a USB-C to USB3 adapter to connect my USB sticks to the MacBook

I even tried to make a Kali live image, using their Apple Silicon image, but the mcbook is still showing "Machintosh HD" only in the boot options.

How can I boot any Linux distribution on my Mac?
If booting a live system is not possible, do you have any suggestion on how could I get a disk image of the MacBook "from outside" ?

Comment: Pretty shure it’s a nope and covered. Please edit to clarify how this is different than the linked question if needed

Comment: Kali doesn't have an ASi image.  Kali has an ARM build, but it's not something you can boot on the bare metal.

Comment: A2179 is Intel.